# return a smarty template to a html text box

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I want to use smarty to return some html to a text box in the back end of my web site. I am already using smarty to render the backend itself.

Whats the best way to do this?

I'm assigning a single array to smarty in the usual way, but not sure how then to return the template.

Comment: You need to explain this better. Do you want to receive Smarty-generated content via AJAX to use in a text box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fetch the content of an template with smarty use:

```
$oSmartyObject->fetch('template.tpl');
```

It will use any variables assigned, and you can use the content as you wish.